# Unable to access processMouseMotionEvent from component

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, access-modifiers

I'm trying to emulate the mouse in a component in a JFrame, and I've come across `processMouseMotionEvent`. Supposedly I can pass a `MouseEvent` to this and it will process the MouseEvent in the component. I've tried this, but I get an error:

`processMouseMotionEvent(MouseEvent) has protected access in JComponent.`

I take it this means I'm doing this wrong and that I'm not supposed to be using the method how I am? This is a snippet of my code currently. How else can I process an emulated MouseEvent in a component if this wont work?

```
JWebBrowser j = new JWebBrowser();
j.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
j.processMouseMotionEvent(new MouseEvent(this, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 2, false)); //ERROR
panel.add(j);
```

Comment: It sounds like your trying to re/dispatch the event manual. Have a look at [this for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449502/passing-the-click-event-on-one-jpanel-to-another-jpanel/21468973#21468973)

Answer (score 2):

The error means exactly what it says -- that you're trying to call a protected method by an outside class where it is not accessible, not visible. I don't know if what you are trying to do is a viable plan, but regardless, if you need to access an inherited protected method, then you should consider creating a public wrapper method that outside objects can call and that calls your protected method method.

e.g.,

```
// or whatever you're extending...
public class MyFoo extends JComponent {

   // the wrapper method *must* be public
   public void processMouseMotionEventWrapper(MouseEvent mEvt) {
      processMouseMotionEvent(mEvt);
   }
}
```

Again, I cannot speak for whether your using this method is a good idea as I have never used it.

Comment: Ok I've done that, but how do I call it specific to the JComponent? Like instead of doing `j.processMouseMotionEvent...`, I can't do `j.MouseWrapper`, how would I do it?

Comment: @Nathan: I'm not sure that I understand your question. A wrapper would only work in an extended class.

Comment: Does this method not require a component? Like j.setBounds, it doesn't really mean much without j. If I call my wrapper, with no mention of j at all, how will the program know to process the mouse specific to that component? Or is this not important?

Comment: @Nathan: the method is declared **inside** of your class that extends some JComponent. You call it on objects of your class, and on these objects only. Other than that, your questions above are confusing the hell out of me.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted what processMouseMotionEvent does exactly which might be why I'm confusing you. I'll give this a whirl and hopefully it works, thanks!